# How to Keep active state of an item inside of component that iterates over some dataset

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have array with objects (posts - strings), and I need to have an opportunity to edit every of them, but In my case when I press on button, it starts to edit all of them:

```
const [editMode, setEditMode] = useState<any>(false);

  let activeStatusChange = () => {
    setEditMode(true);
  };

    <div>
      {posts?.map((el) => (
                <div key={Number(el.id)}>
                    { 
                        editMode === true
                        ?   <p>{<input />}</p>
                        :   <div>{el.body}
                                <button onClick={activeStatusChange}>edit</button>
                            </div>
                    }
                       
                </div>
            
      ))}
```

Comment: you need to assign an id to your elements and pass that id throgh the click handler. and then you can enable / disable edit mode according to the selected id

Comment: @messerbill please, can you show small example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are lopping on every `posts` element of your component and applying  your handler `activeStatusChange` on every one of them and thats runes every thing! :)

you need to keep track of active post to activate/deactivate it!
you might have an `id` for your data (`posts`) or if you don't you can use the id of your loop to keep track of your active element, also for doing that you need to use id instead of true/false value:

```
const [editableItemId, setEditableItemId] = useState<number | null>(null);

  let activeStatusChange = (targetId: number) : void => {
    setEditMode(Number(targetId));
  };

    <div>
      {posts?.map((el) => (
         <div key={el.id}>
            { 
              editableItemId === el.id
                ? <p><input /></p>
                : <div>{el.body}
                    <button onClick={() => activeStatusChange(el.id)}>edit</button>
                  </div>
            }
                       
         </div>
            
      ))}
```